# PHP imagejpeg() unable to open directory

Tags: php, gd

Every time I try to write an image using `imagejpeg()`, I get the following error:

```
Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open '/home/userdir/public_html/files/images/thumbs/
```

I've checked and this dir has `777` permissions, so it should be able to write to it.

Stranger still, the destination file path being given to `imagejpeg()` is actually:

```
/home/userdir/public_html/files/images/thumbs/small/1113/XM324980.jpg
```

I've checked, and permissions are set to `777` all the way.  The file doesn't already exist.

Why would it be having trouble opening the "thumbs" dir to write to the `thumbs/small/1113/` dir?

Comment: Does the `/small/1113/` directory exists?

Comment: Don't set permission to `777` ever. Cordially, your sysadmin.

Comment: Show some code, if you want accurate answers.

Comment: TBH you don't need to be able to write to it.  The user the webserver is running under needs to be able to write to it.  Not that that is your problem though.

Comment: @InternetSeriousBusiness Yeah, it was changed just to make sure that wasn't causing a problem.  Changed it right back after debugging the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `imagejpeg()` will only create the image in the destination directory but you have used another two sub-directories that is `small/1113` for creating the directories you have to use the `mkdir` functionality. Please make sure you have created that first and then create the images inside it.

Comment: Actually, I thought I was creating it! Turns out I made a dumb mistake, because the code that checked if the subdir exists was checking the source dir instead of the destination dir.  Changed that and it works great now.  Thanks! :)